# Modules did not load correctly

Tags: wifi, drivers, usb, ethernet

I had tried to insert a “hello ,world“ kernel module in my Ubuntu: version `16.04`.

But it throws

```
cannot stat './modules.order' : no such file or directory'.
```

After that, I rebooted my system. Now ethernet, wifi, and usb are not detected in my system. While trying to install my “hello ,world“ module, I think I have done some mistake. And at boot time it shows failed to load kernel modules.

How to recover it?

Answer (score 1):

`modules.order` is a file that is supposed to be located at `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.order`. It is normally generated by the `depmod` command, which should normally run as part of normal start-up if necessary.

Please verify that the disk containing the `/lib/modules` directory is not 100% full; if necessary, try and find a way to free some space.

Then run `sudo depmod` to see if it produces any error messages. If all goes well, it should produce no messages at all. If it runs successfully, reboot.

Comment: To anyone else finding this situation: In Debian sid, it’s now in `/usr/lib/modules/…` so current kernels can no longer be installed on systems with actually-supported-by-`dpkg` filesystem layouts. (Or rather, they can, but their `initramfs` will no longer contain everything necessary.) This is tricky when upgrading debian-ports architectures (sid-only) especially, as they have no intermediate releases to do this safely.